# The Hausdorff condition in an exercise in Willard's General Topology

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Exercise 17S (p.129) in S. Willard's General Topology asks to prove the Alexander subbase theorem (AST) and then use it to provide a proof of the Tychonoff theorem (TT).

Consider a familly $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of compact spaces, and let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$.

Having proved AST, for the difficult implication of TT, I consider the subbase $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of all open sets of the form $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U)$, where the $U$ are open in $X_{\alpha}$. That is,
$$\mathcal{B}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U):U\;\mbox{is open in $X_{\alpha}$}\}.$$

Then I proceed to show that any finitely inadequate subfamily $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ is inadequate. ($\mathcal{A}$ is finitely inadequate iff no finite subfamily covers $X$, and inadequate iff it fails to cover $X$).

For each $\alpha\in I$, I consider the set $B_{\alpha}=\{V\subseteq X_{\alpha}: V\;\mbox{is open and $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal{A}$}\}$, show that this set is finitely inadequate and, by compactness of $X_{\alpha}$, also inadequate. Therefore, for each $\alpha\in I$ there is at least one element in $X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$. We use the axiom of choice to choose for each $\alpha\in I$ an element $x_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$.

The point $x=(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$ is not in $\bigcup\mathcal{A}$, showing that $\mathcal{A}$ is inadequate, and thus proving the compactness of $X$, as desired.

**My question is this: If each $X_{\alpha}$ is a Hausdorff space, does it follow that each $X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$ is a singleton?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, each $X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$ is a singleton. However,  I use the ultrafilter theorem to prove it.

Since $B_{\alpha}$ is finitely inadequate, the collection $B_{\alpha}^{*}=\{X_{\alpha}-U:U\in B_{\alpha}\}$ has the finite intersection property, and it generates a filter $F$ which is contained in an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ (by the ultrafilter theorem).

Moreover, since $B_{\alpha}$ is inadequate
$$\displaystyle{\emptyset\neq X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha} = \bigcap B_{\alpha}^{*}\subseteq\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{F}}\bar{A}}.$$

Therefore, for any point $x_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$, every neighborhood $V$ of $x_{\alpha}$ in $X_{\alpha}$ verifies $V\in\mathcal{F}$ because $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter and $V\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$.

In conclusion, if $x_{\alpha},y_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}-\bigcup B_{\alpha}$, then every neighborhood of each is in $\mathcal{F}$ and therefore, for any two neighborhoods of $x_{\alpha}\in V$ and $y_{\alpha}\in W$ we have $V\cap W\neq\emptyset$. But $X_{\alpha}$ is Hausdorff, implying $x_{\alpha}=y_{\alpha}$, as desired.

Is there simpler proof without using the ultrafilter theorem?